# simple OGNL projection required in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, projection, ognl

I would like to create a really simple  tag parameterized with a collections' ids something like the following:

```
<s:url action="theaction" namespace="/" includeParams="all" id="histURL">
 <s:param name="sources" value="sources.{id}"></s:param>
</s:url>
${histURL}
```

If I have say three Source objects defined in my Action class, having ids 1,2 and 3 then I assume, the histURL output will be sg like:

```
http://localhost:8080/myproject/theaction&sources=1&sources=2&sources=3
```

But it does not work, it displays:

```
http://localhost:8080/myproject/theaction
```

Another hint:

```
<s:url action="theaction" namespace="/" includeParams="all" id="histURL">
 <s:param name="sources" value="sources"></s:param>
</s:url>
${histURL}
```

results in

```
http://localhost:8080/myproject/theaction&sources=com.mycompany.Source@32324&sources= ...
```

So the collection as a paramater works, I just assumed that the [OGNL projection](http://www.opensymphony.com/ognl/html/LanguageGuide/projection.html) works well but seems to be buggy. Or am I missing something? Is this OGNL at all? :)

Thank you for your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm dumb. 
This is just the way, I missed that I used a wrong class, which had no Id at all.
It's definitely OGNL and it works like charm :)